# How to return data from multiple nodes in a cypher query to a single graphql field?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphql

I have been trying a few workarounds for a while to return the right results to graphql from a Neo4j query.

Let's take a search query as an example:

```
search: {
    args: {
        term: { type: GraphQLString }
    },
    type: new GraphQLList(NodeType),
    resolve(parentValue, { term }, ctx) {
        let params = { term };
        let query = "MATCH(n:node) WHERE n.name CONTAINS { term } RETURN DISTINCT n.name, LABELS(n), n.userID, ID(n);";
         return session.run(query, params)
             .then( result => {
                 const record = result.records;
                 return record.map(function (data) {
                     return {
                          name: data.get('n.name'),
                          id: data.get('ID(n)').low,
                          userID: data.get('n.userID'),
                          label: data.get('LABELS(n)')[0]
                     }
                 })
            })
     }
}
```

This returns all the nodes that contain a certain string value in their name property without problem. But how to return the same properties to a single GraphQL field if you describe more nodes in the Neo4j query? When you add an optianal match for example:

```
MATCH(n:node) 
WHERE n.name CONTAINS { term } 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:nodeOf]-(b) 
RETURN DISTINCT n.name, LABELS(n), n.userID, ID(n);
```

In here you need to return data from two nodes, `n` and `b`. I tried to set the path to a variable:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(n)-[:nodeOf]-(b)
```

But then I run into the problem that I can't get certain data, for example the length as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848994/how-to-return-the-length-of-nodes-in-a-variable-path).

So if you have a query that describes two nodes, like `(a)-[r]-(b)`, then how do you return both `a.name` and `b.name` to this single GraphQL object type's `name` field?

This is what a simple version of the NodeType looks like:

```
const NodeType = new GraphQLObjectType ({
   name: 'Node',
   fields: () => ({
       id: { type: GraphQLInt },
       userID: { type: GraphQLInt },
       name: { type: GraphQLString},
       label: { type: GraphQLString },
       depth: { type: GraphQLInt },      
   })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can do something like:

```
MATCH(n:node) 
WHERE n.name CONTAINS { term } 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:nodeOf]-(b) 
WITH collect({name : n.name})  + collect({name : b.name}) AS allNodes
UNWIND allNodes AS node
RETURN node
```

In this query, I'm [collecting](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) `a.name` and `b.name` in the same collection (`allNodes`). Then, I'm using [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) to transform the list to individual rows back.

Comment: I didn't know it's possible to collect multiple collections using `+`. Thanks a lot!